# Is a browser's console an interface to the web API?

Tags: google-chrome, web, browser, webapi, javascript-engine

From my research, the browser gives us some features that the JavaScript engine itself doesn’t provide: a Web API. This includes the DOM API, setTimeout, HTTP requests, and so on.

So because browsers run functions that are not supported in the JavaScript engine, like setTimeout for example, is it correct to say that the browser's terminal is an interface to the web and Web API.

Does that make sense, is that a constructive way to think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the WebAPI and the Console are two separate Things  that both plug into the js-engine of your browser. The Console is not able to directly access the DOM for example, it can only execute javascript lines, that access the DOM internal and return a specific result (again returned via javascript)